# Add a wish list of products the user wants

Tags: feature-request

I would like to propose my idea: Have you thought of a "wish list" in which users can link to any product found on the web that would like to receive as a gift?

This would give you direct access to statistics on the consumption habits (divided by age, income, education, etc.) and would give you the opportunity to also contact the producers directly to inform them of these preferences and encourage commercial activities targeted on the site.

Comment: Not gonna happen. Why would Stack Exchange care at all? If you're so concerned about your wish list, just link to one in your profile, like an Amazon wish list. :) Happy days!

Comment: How is this related to Stack Exchange at all?

Comment: To put it bluntly. This is a bad idea. Keep 'em coming though. ;)

Comment: I disagree with this request, but I'm voting to reopen because I don't see how it's off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

This would be a good idea *if* we wanted to encourage commercial activities targeted on the site.

But we don't, if anything we actively discourage commercial activities targeted on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange in general. You can add your wish list to your profile's about box, and that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you thought of a "wish list" in which users can link to any product found on the web that would like to receive as a gift?

I suppose it would be acceptable if you created a "wish list" in your own "About me" box (just don't expect to get anything from it), but to create a feature which allows users to  create a wish list seems shady at best.

> This would give you direct access to statistics on the consumption habits (divided by age, income, education, etc.)

In what way? The majority of users don't input their age, Stack Overflow has no idea about anyone's income or education unless they specifically state it in their "About me" box.

> and would give you the opportunity to also contact the producers directly to inform them of these preferences

Why would Stack Exchange sites have any interest in doing that? Do you expect producers to pay for the information? Because producers aren't willing to pay to learn how many programmers on a website said they wanted one of their products. It would be, quite frankly, a pointless statistic because there's not enough variables defined and not enough people would fill out the wish list to make it worthwhile anyways.

> encourage commercial activities targeted on the site.

Because that's exactly what we want. Maybe we could create some spam bots that let everyone know about the latest penis enlargement pill products while we're at it, too.

Comment: `I suppose it would be acceptable if you created a "wish list" in your own "About me" box` Actually it's quite common, I've seen several users doing it, and it's perfectly fine (it's your about box, if you aren't being offensive, you can put anything you want in it)

Comment: @YannisRizos - Well, those were probably high-rep users who actually deserve some gifts. The OP doesn't an account on any other SE sites and this is his only question on this one. I wouldn't be offended if I saw a wish list in his about me box, but I would think it was strange.

Comment: Doesn't really matter what the OP's contributions are, if they want to put a wish list in their about box, they should feel free. People are free to ignore it...

Comment: @YannisRizos - I know, that's why I said it would be acceptable. =p   The hesitancy evident in my post was from my confusion on why he would, not my reluctance to "allow" him to do so.